# Check if a spelled number is in a range in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, numbers

I want to check the (numeric) input against a list of ranges (min,max) while the input is partially typed in; in other words, I need an elegant algorithm to check the prefix of a number against a range (without using regular expressions).

Sample testcases:

```
 1 is in (  5,   9) -> false
 6 is in (  5,   9) -> true
 1 is in (  5,  11) -> true  (as 10 and 11 are in the range)
 1 is in (  5, 200) -> true  (as e.g. 12 and 135 are in the range)
11 is in (  5,  12) -> true
13 is in (  5,  12) -> false 
13 is in (  5,  22) -> true
13 is in (  5, 200) -> true  (as 130 is in the range)
 2 is in (100, 300) -> true  (as 200 is in the range)
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Read the number and use operators `<, >, <=, >=`?

Comment: @Kiril: No, he needs to know if there's a prefix match also

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? Also, are you asking about `C` or `C++` (the answer will be different, depending upon the required language.)

Comment: @BenVoigt - aaah, right, I didn't read all examples.

Comment: What about `14 is in (4, 10)` The range contains both digits of 14, is that true or not?

Comment: @jrok: No, that's definitely false.  The user would never type `14` on his way to any number between `4` and `10`.

Comment: In addition, it supposed to appear as prefix and not other form.

Comment: @BenVoigt Right, I missed the "while the input is typed" part.

Comment: Does it have to be prefix?  Would `2 in range(11, 13)` return `True`?

Comment: is it safe to no negative numbers are allowed?

Comment: @japreiss: Possibly in a culture with RTL reading order (I don't know what order the digits would be placed in such cultures).

Comment: Seems, you find something like 'fuzzy search' algorithm.

Comment: related http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/38874/11086

Answer (score 27):

I believe it's true that the input is acceptable if and only if either:

- It is a prefix substring of the lower bound converted to string

or

- The input followed by any number of additional zeros (possibly none) falls into the range

The first rule is required by e.g. `13 is in range (135, 140)`.  The second rule is required by e.g. `2 is in range (1000, 3000)`.

The second rule can be efficiently tested by a series of multiplies by 10, until the scaled input exceeds the upper bound.

Comment: I believe it's rather "The input followed by additional _digits_ falls into the range". At least I think it would make more sense.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: Nope, I claim it's only necessary to test with trailing zeros in the second rule.

Comment: look at the third case: "1 is in (  5,  11) -> true  (as 10 **and 11** are in the range)". 11 here is interpreted as the inputted number (1) followed by another digit (1), or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: @Singer: But because `10` is in range, you're done testing, you already know the result is true.

Comment: Can't it be suffix as well. See no example, disagrees. Also the question title, may allow substring as well.

Comment: @vinayak: I interpret "while the number is typed in" to mean that the user may add additional digits to the end of the input, the algorithm is required to test whether doing so might make the input in range.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Can you prove this?

Comment: The first rule is obviously sufficient. If I've entered AB and the lower bound is ABC, entering C will be in range. It's not necessary as there may other ways to get a number in range, see the second example. The second rule is similarly sufficient, but not necessary. The **true** proof needed is that at least one of the two is necessary.

Comment: These rules don't cover the case "*8 is in (7, 12)*". "8" is not a prefix of the lower bound, and "80" is outside the range. The second rule must be "*The input followed by zero or more additional zeros falls into the range*"

Comment: @Rob: Umm, yes, any number of additional zeros can be zero additional zeros.  I'll clarify.

Comment: @Robᵩ, your update rule also wrong, IMHO, the second rule is _"The input followed by zero or more additional zeros smaller than upper bound"_.Look at my [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12566415/1177288)

Comment: @T_12: No, consider: `13 in range (1200, 1299)`.  `13 < 1299` is true (your rule), but the correct answer is false.

Comment: @BenVoigt, that's right, it needs addtitional rule. However my solution works on (13,1200,1299)

Comment: A minor pedantic point: we also need to check that min<=max first otherwise (13, 13, 12) might be accepted!

Comment: @Mark: Sure, and if you pass in a NULL pointer instead of actual input then bad things happen also.  The question asked for an algorithm, not how to handle invalid inputs.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I did say it was pedantic :-)

Answer (score 8):

An iterative formulation:

```
bool in_range(int input, int min, int max)
{
  if (input <= 0)
    return true;    // FIXME handle negative and zero-prefixed numbers
  int multiplier = 1;
  while ((input + 1) * multiplier - 1 < min)         // min <= [input]999
    multiplier *= 10;    // TODO consider overflow
  return input * multiplier <= max;                  //        [input]000 <= max
}
```

A simpler [edit: and more efficent; see below] method is to use truncating integer division:

```
bool in_range(int input, int min, int max)
{
  if (input <= 0)
    return true;
  while (input < min) {
    min /= 10;
    max /= 10;
  }
  return input <= max;
}
```

---

Testing and profiling:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

bool ecatmur_in_range_mul(int input, int min, int max)
{
  int multiplier = 1;
  while ((input + 1) * multiplier - 1 < min)         // min <= [input]999
    multiplier *= 10;    // TODO consider overflow
  return input * multiplier <= max;                  //        [input]000 <= max
}

bool ecatmur_in_range_div(int input, int min, int max)
{
  while (input < min) {
    min /= 10;
    max /= 10;
  }
  return input <= max;
}

bool t12_isInRange(int input, int min, int max)
{
    int multiplier = 1;
    while(input*multiplier <= max)
    {
        if(input >= min / multiplier) return true;
        multiplier *= 10;
    }
    return false;
}

struct algo { bool (*fn)(int, int, int); const char *name; } algos[] = {
{ ecatmur_in_range_mul, "ecatmur_in_range_mul"},
{ ecatmur_in_range_div, "ecatmur_in_range_div"},
{ t12_isInRange, "t12_isInRange"},
};

struct test { int input, min, max; bool result; } tests[] = {
{  1,   5,   9, false },
{  6,   5,   9, true },
{  1,   5,  11, true }, // as 10 and 11 are in the range
{  1,   5, 200, true }, // as e.g. 12 and 135 are in the range
{ 11,   5,  12, true },
{ 13,   5,  12, false },
{ 13,   5,  22, true },
{ 13,   5, 200, true }, // as 130 is in the range
{  2, 100, 300, true }, // as 200 is in the range
{ 13, 135, 140, true }, // Ben Voigt
{ 13, 136, 138, true }, // MSalters
};
int main() {
    for (auto a: algos)
        for (auto t: tests)
            if (a.fn(t.input, t.min, t.max) != t.result)
                std::cout << a.name << "(" << t.input << ", " << t.min << ", " << t.max << ") != "
                    << t.result << "\n";

    for (auto a: algos) {
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        for (auto t: tests)
            for (int i = 1; i < t.max * 2; ++i)
                for (volatile int j = 0; j < 1000; ++j) {
                    volatile bool r = a.fn(i, t.min, t.max);
                    (void) r;
                }
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::cout << a.name << ": "
            << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Surprisingly (at least to me) iterated division comes out fastest:

```
ecatmur_in_range_mul: 17331000
ecatmur_in_range_div: 14711000
t12_isInRange: 15646000
```

Comment: Already proposed and still fails to check `13 in (135, 140)`.

Comment: @BenVoigt fixed (at least for that case).

Comment: I like your new solution, the first solution still looks very wrong.  See MSalters comment on `T_12` answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt for `(13, 136, 138)` the first solution loop stops at `multiplier = 10` because `(13 + 1) * 10 - 1 = 139 >= 136`; then `13 * 10 <= 138` so it returns `true`.

Comment: Oh ok.  Yeah that variation does appear to fix it.

Comment: @Bitwise all three iterative methods are correct solutions, and are compared above.

Answer (score 3):

```
bool isInRange(int input, int min, int max)
{
    int multiplier = 1;
    while(input*multiplier <= max)
    {
        if(input >= min / multiplier) return true;
        multiplier *= 10;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It pass all your testcases.

Comment: Fails for `13 in (135, 140)`.

Comment: Adding `input +=9`.would fix that testcase, but break `in (136, 138)`. You really need a bunch of testcases.

Comment: Yup. This is now the numerical version of Ben Voights answer. The `input*multiplier <= max` part is equivalent to the "add zeroes" rule; the `input >= min / multiplier` part is equivalent to the "prefix substring of lowerbound" rule.

Comment: @MSalters: Not exactly, the "prefix substring" rule is equivalent to `input == min / multiplier`, not `>=`, and, of course, Ben Voight 's rules are alternative (OR), but mine rules are AND

Comment: @T_12: DeMorgan's theorem shows that OR and AND are quite interchangeable.  But you do have OR, insofar as you have multiple chances to `return true` (one chance per loop iteration).

Answer (score 2):

One trivial solution is to generate all N-digit prefixes in range. So, for `11 is in (  5,  12)` you want the two-digit prefixes of all numbers between 5 and 12. Obviously that's just 10, 11 and 12.

In general, for numbers X to Y, the possible N-digit prefixes can be obtained by the following algorithm:

```
X = MIN(X, 10^(N-1) ) ' 9 has no 2-digit prefix so start at 10
Y = Y - (Y MOD 10^N)  ' 1421 has the same 2 digit prefix as 1400
WHILE (X < Y)
  LIST_PREFIX += PREFIX(N, X) ' Add the prefix of X to the list.
  X += 10^(TRUNCATE(LOG10(X)) - N+1) ' For N=2, go from 1200 to 1300
```

Comment: Agreed on not elegant, but why is it not efficient?

Comment: Oh wait, I misread it as enumerating all numbers starting with the input.  How do you handle the range (5, 12000)?

Comment: With prefix 87? N=2, so minimum is 10, maximum is 12000. Add prefix 10, step +1 up to 99. From there, +10 to 999, +100 to 9999, +1000 to 11999. Since the step size depends on the prefix length needed, for numbers `N+M` with digits it samples only 1 in `M` numbers and still gets all prefixes of length `N`

Comment: Well, there's the "not very efficient".  You've got a list of several hundred values, but only about half a dozen tests were needed.

Comment: Yeah, you can obviously stop earlier. Once you've gone over the desired prefix, you can skip directly to `X=10^(next N)`, and if you already had prefix 10^N you can quit.

Answer (score 2):

```
(input >= lower_bound) && input <= upper_bound

OR

(f(input) >= lower_bound) && (f(input) <= upper_bound)

OR

(lower_bound - f(input) < pow(10, n_digits_upper_bound - n_digits_input)) && 
(lower_bound - f(input) > 0)

where

f(input) == (input * pow(10, n_digits_upper_bound - n_digits_input))


 1 is in (  5,   9) -> 1 * pow(10,0) -> same                 -> false
 6 is in (  5,   9)                                          -> true
 1 is in (  5,  11) -> 1 * pow(10,1)  -> 10 is in (5,11)     -> true
 1 is in (  5, 200) -> 1 * pow(10,2)  -> 100 is in (5, 200)  -> true
11 is in (  5,  12)                                          -> true
13 is in (  5,  12) -> 13 * pow(10,0) -> same                -> false 
13 is in (  5,  22)                                          -> true
13 is in (  5, 200)                                          -> true
 2 is in (100, 300) -> 2 * pow(10,2) -> 200 is in (100,300)  -> true
 4 is in (100, 300) -> 4 * pow(10,2)  -> 400 is in (100,300) -> false
13 is in (135, 140) -> 135 - 130                             -> true
14 is in (135, 139) -> 135 - 140                             -> false
```

Comment: Try `13 in (135, 140)`.  Why does everyone keep suggesting the same broken solution?

Comment: `(lower_bound - f(input) < 10) && (lower_bound - f(input) > 0)`  
should be  
`(lower_bound - f(input) < pow(10, n_digits_upper_bound - n_digits_input)) && (lower_bound - f(input) > 0)`  
as for `13 in (1350, 1400)`

Answer (score 2):

I prefer an approach which uses already implemented algorithms. While a lot of other solution use recursive divisions by `10`, I think it's better to make use of 10-base logarithms, which have `O(1)` complexity, so that the whole solution complexity is `O(1)`.

Let us split the problem into two parts.

**First** part will handle the case when the `number * 10^n` is between `min` and `max` for at least one `n`. This would let us check for example if `number = 12` and `min,max = 11225,13355`, that `x = 12000 = 12*10^3` is between `min` and `max`. If this test checks out, it means the result is `True`.

**Second** part will handle the cases when `number` is beginning of either `min` or `max`. For example if `number = 12` and `min,max = 12325,14555`, the first test will fail, as `12000` is not between `min` and `max` (as well as will fail all other numbers `12*10^n` for any `n`). But second test will find that `12` is the beginning of `12325` and return `True`.

## First

Let's check, if the first `x = number*10^n`, which is equal or larger than `min`, is smaller or equal than `max` (so `min <= x <= max, where x is number*10^n for any integer n`). If it's bigger than `max`, than all other `x`es will be bigger, as we took the smallest.

```
log(number*10^n) > log(min)
log(number) + log(10^n) > log(min)
log(number) + n > log(min)
n > log(min) - log(number)
n > log(min/number)
```

To get the number to compare with, we just calculate the first satisfactory `n`:

```
n = ceil(log(min/number))
```

And calculate then number `x`:

```
x = number*10^n
```

## Second

We should check if our number is a literal beginning of either boundary.

We just calculate `x` beginning with the same digits as `number` and padded with `0`s on the end, having the same length as `min`:

```
magnitude = 10**(floor(log10(min)) - floor(log10(number)))
x = num*magnitude
```

And then check if `min`'s and `x` difference (in magnitude scale) is less than `1` and bigger or equal to `0`:

```
0 <= (min-x)/magnitude < 1
```

So, if `number` is `121` and `min` is `132125`, then `magnitude` is `1000`, `x = number*magnitude` would be `121000`. `min - x` gives `132125-121000 = 11125`, which should be smaller than `1000` (otherwise `min` beginning would be bigger than `121`), so we compare it with `magnitude` by dividing by it's value and comparing to `1`. And it's OK if `min` is `121000`, but not OK if `min` is `122000`, that is why `0 <=` and `< 1`.

The same algorithm is for `max`.

## Pseudo code

Incorporating it all in pseudo code gives this algorithm:

```
def check(num,min,max):
    # num*10^n is between min and max
    #-------------------------------
    x = num*10**(ceil(log10(min/num)))
    if x>=min and x<=max: 
        return True

    # if num is prefix substring of min
    #-------------------------------
    magnitude = 10**(floor(log10(min)) - floor(log10(num)))
    if 0 <= (min-num*magnitude)/magnitude < 1:
        return True

    # if num is prefix substring of max
    #-------------------------------
    magnitude = 10**(floor(log10(max)) - floor(log10(num)))
    if 0 <= (max-num*magnitude)/magnitude < 1:
        return True

    return False
```

This code could be optimized by avoiding repeated calculations of `log10(num)`. Also, in final solution I would go from float to integer scope (`magnitude = 10**int(floor(log10(max)) - floor(log10(num)))`) and then perform all comparisons without division, i.e. `0 <= (max-num*magnitude)/magnitude < 1` -> `0 <= max-num*magnitude < magnitude`. This would alleviate possibilities of round-off errors.

Also, it may be possible to replace `magnitude = 10**(floor(log10(min)) - floor(log10(num)))`  with `magnitude = 10**(floor(log10(min/num)))`, where `log10` is calculated only once. But I can't prove that it will always bring correct results, nor can I disprove it. If anybody could prove it, I would be very grateful.

<sub>Tests (in Python): http://ideone.com/N5R2j (you could edit input to add another tests).</sub>

Comment: @MSalters This means that I didn't grasped what is needed. Because I tested on the tests provided in the question.

Comment: @MSalters Updated to reflect the bug.

Answer (score 2):

Given a value *n*, begin with the half-open range [*n*, *n* + 1) and proceed by orders of magnitude:

- [10*n*, 10(*n* + 1))
- [100*n*, 100(*n* + 1))
- [1000*n*, 1000(*n* + 1))
- …

Continue until the iterated range overlaps the target range, or the two ranges can no longer overlap.

```
#include <iostream>

bool overlaps(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
  return a < c && c < b || c < a && a < d;
}

bool intersects(int first, int begin, int end) {
  int last = first + 1;
  ++end;
  while (first <= end) {
    if (overlaps(first, last, begin, end))
      return true;
    first *= 10;
    last *= 10;
  }
  return false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha
    << intersects( 1,   5,   9) << '\n'
    << intersects( 6,   5,   9) << '\n'
    << intersects( 1,   5,  11) << '\n'
    << intersects( 1,   5, 200) << '\n'
    << intersects(11,   5,  12) << '\n'
    << intersects(13,   5,  12) << '\n'
    << intersects(13,   5,  22) << '\n'
    << intersects(13,   5, 200) << '\n'
    << intersects( 2, 100, 300) << '\n'
    << intersects(13, 135, 140) << '\n';
}
```

Using ranges is necessary to prevent missed cases. Consider *n* = 2 and a target range of [21, 199]. 2 is not in the range, so we multiply by 10; 20 is not in the range, so we multiply by 10 again; 200 is not in the range, nor any higher number, so the naive algorithm terminates with a false negative.

Comment: Using ranges is not necessary.  My first rule avoids your example of a false negative.

Answer (score 2):

I came to this new simple solution while thinking on a proof for @Ben Voigt 's beautiful solution:

Let's go back to elementary school where we did number comparison.
Question would be like: check if the number "*A*" is in the range of number "*B*" and number "*C*"

Solution: Adding the necessary Zeros to the left side of numbers (so we have equal number of digits in all numbers) We start from the leftmost digit. compare it with the equivalent digit in the other two numbers.

- if the digit from *A* is less than the digit from *B* or more than the digit from *C*, then *A* is not in the range.
- if not we repeat the process with the next digit from *A* and equivalents from *B* and *C*.

**IMPORTANT QUESTION:** Why don't we stop right there? Why do we check the next digits?

**IMPORTANT ANSWER:** Because the digit from *A* being between the equivalents from *B* and *C* is O.K. **up to now** but not enough reason yet to make a decision! (obvious right?)

This, in turn, means there could be a set of digits which could put *A* out of the range.

AND, LIKEWISE

**There could be a set of digits which could put *A* inside the range**

**which is another way of saying *A* could be a prefix of a number in the range.**

Isn't that what we were looking for?! :D

The backbone of the algorithm would be basically a simple comparison for each input event:

1. Add some zero (if necessary) at the left of *min* so that the length of *min* and *max* would become equal.
2. compare input *A* with the equivalent digits from *min* and *max* (cut the corresponding digits of *min* and *max* from **left**, and **not right**)
3. Is input *A* <= corresponding part of *max* **AND** >= corresponding part of *min*? (no: return false, yes: return true)

false and true here express the situation "up to now", as the problem requires.

Comment: How can I call everyone for a feedback?
I would love to see some feedback.
This is my first activity in stackoverflow.com and I don't know my way around this place much.
@Ben Voigt What is your opinion on this solution?

Comment: Edited the post: Added the "Adding Zero to the left side of numbers"
 and edited the post based on that.

Comment: I think I'm having serious problem with my description. Tried putting the post under extensive editing. Sorry, my bad.
But I think I have managed to deliver the overall sense of the solution. 
Any feedback would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you might have problems with `25 in (290, 310)` since 2 is between (2,3) and 5 is between (1,9), but 25 is not a prefix for any number in range.  As well, `39 in (2500, 4700)`, the 9 is not in the range (5,7).  So you need to be careful about *earlier digit was the same as the digit in `min`* vs `earlier digit is greater than the corresponding digit in `min`*.  I guess that's what your step 5 and 6 do?

Comment: @BenVoigt You were right.

I changed the algorithm so that it takes into account, the earlier digits to so in your first case, now, 25 would be compared against (29,31) and not 5 against (1,9). This solves the problem you mentioned and surprisingly simplifies the whole algorithm.

I also changed the algorithm so that it should get called with each input digit.

By golly, it's just come down to simple comparison! 

The whole point of this solution is in the **IMPORTANT QUESTION** and it's **IMPORTANT ANSWER** which proves the validity of the simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

All the hard cases are situations in which the lower bound has less digits then the upper bound. Just break the range in two (or three). If AB is the union of sets A and B, then `x in AB` implies `x in A` or `x in B`. So:

`13 is in (5,  12)` => `13 is in (5, 9)` OR `13 is in (10, 12)`

`13 is in (5,  120)` => `13 is in (5, 9)` OR `13 is in (10, 99)` OR `13 is in (100, 120)`

Then, **truncate** to match lengths. I.e.

`13 is in (5, 120)` => <strike>`13 is in (5, 9)` OR</strike>  `13 is in (10, 99)` OR `13 is in (10`<strike>0</strike>`, 12`<strike>0</strike>`)`

After this second rewrite, it becomes a simple numeric check. Note that if you have the range `10,99` appear then you have all possible 2-digit prefixes and don't actually need to check, but that's an optimization. (I'm assuming we ignore prefixes 00-09)

Comment: Yeah I considered doing that, but it's unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes another answer. For input X and bounds MIN and MAX

```
WHILE (X < MIN)
  IF X is a prefix of MIN
    x = 10*x + next digit of MIN
  ELSE
    x = 10*x
RETURN (x>= MIN && x<=MAX)
```

This works by "typing" the next lowest digit. So the hard case `13 in (135, 140)` adds a 5 to produce 135, not a zero.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the implementation method you chose, you should consider building a lot of unit tests. Because you're asking the question just as you would have written a test for test-driven development (TDD). So I suggest that, while you are waiting for a suitable algorithm to pop out of stack overflow, write your unit tests:

Make your test fail if the examples you give don't yield the results in your examples. Write a couple of other limit test cases just to be sure. Then, if you happen to use a wrong or buggy algorithm, you will know it soon. Once your test passes, you'll know that you've reached your goal.

Plus, it shields you from any regression in the future

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm under-thinking this but assuming that the Min-Max range of integers are all positive (i.e. greater than or equal to zero), this code block should do the trick nicely:

```
bool CheckRange(int InputValue, int MinValue, int MaxValue)
{
    // Assumes that:
    //    1. InputValue >= MinValue 
    //    2. MinValue >= 0
    //    3. MinValue <= MaxValue 
    //
    if (InputValue < 0)         // The input value is less than zero
        return false;
    //
    if (InputValue > MaxValue)  // The input value is greater than max value
        return false;
    //
    if (InputValue == 0 && InputValue < MinValue)
        return false;       // The input value is zero and less than a non-zero min value
    //
    int WorkValue = InputValue; // Seed a working variable
    //
    while (WorkValue <= MaxValue)
    {
        if (WorkValue >= MinValue && WorkValue <= MaxValue)
            return true; // The input value (or a stem) is within range
        else
            WorkValue *= 10; // Not in range, multiply by 10 to check stem again
    }
    //
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, a bit late to the party, but here goes...

Note that we're talking about *user input* here, so it's not sufficient to just `// TODO: consider overflow`. Validating user input is a war, and cutting corners will eventually lead to the detonation of an IED. (Well, ok, maybe not so dramatic, but still...) In fact, *only one* of the algorithms in ecatmur's useful test harness handles a corner case properly (`{23, 2147483644, 2147483646, false}`), and the test harness itself goes into an infinite loop if `t.max` is too big.

The only one which passed was ecatmur_in_range_div, which I think is quite nice. However, it is possible to make it (slightly) faster by adding a few checks:

```
bool in_range_div(int input, int min, int max)
{
  if (input > max) return false;
  if (input >= min) return true;
  if (max / 10 >= min) return true;

  while (input < min) {
    min /= 10;
    max /= 10;
  }
  return input <= max;
}
```

How much faster "depends"; it would be particularly useful if min and max were compile-time constants. The first two tests are obvious, I think; the third one can be proven in a variety of ways but the simplest is to just observe the behaviour of ecatmur's loop: when the loop ends, input is >= min but < 10*min, so if 10*min < max, input must be less than max.

Expressing the arithmetic in terms of division rather than multiplication *ought to be* a habit; I know that most of us grew up with the idea that division is *sloooooow* and must be avoided. However, division, unlike multiplication, will not overflow. Indeed, whenever you find yourself writing:

```
if (a * k < b) ...
```

or

```
for (..., a < b, a *= k)
```

or other variations on those themes, you should immediately flag that as integer overflow, and change it to the equivalent division.

Actually, the same goes for addition except in one important (but common) case:

```
if (a + k < b) ...
```

or

```
a += k; if (a < b) ...
```

are also unsafe **unless** k is one, and you know that a < b before the addition. That exception lets the normal for loop work without too much thought. But watch out for this, which I used to use as part of an interview question:

```
// enumerate every kth element of the range [a, b)
assert(a < b);
for (; a < b; a += k) { ... }
```

Sadly, very few candidates got it.

Answer (score 0):

*I would now delete this answer, except that it shows a failed approach.*

> After checking `Str(min).StartWith(input)`, you need to check numerically if any `10^n*Val(input)` is within the range, as Ben Voight's current answer says.

---

#### Failed attempt

Edited because of Ben Voigt's comment: (I had missed his first point in his current answer: prefix matches to the minimum are OK.)

My solution, based upon @Ben Voigt's insights, is check if `Min` `StartsWith` the current input. If not, `PadRight` the current input with `0` to the length of `Max` as a string. Then if this modified input is *lexically* (i.e. treated as strings) between `Min` and `Max` it's OK.

Pseudo code:

```
 Confirm input has only digits, striping leading 0s
    (most easily done by converting it to an integer and back to a string)

 check = Str(min).StartsWith(input)
 If Not check Then
   testInput = input.PadRight(Len(Str(max)), '0')
   check = Str(min) <= testInput && testInput <= Str(max)
 End If
```

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for pointing this out. I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: Right, you need to use numeric comparison and not lexical in the final check.

Answer (score -1):

```
int input = 15;
int lower_bound = 1561;
int upper_bound = 1567;
int ipow = 0;
while (lower_bound > 0) {
    if (lower_bound > input) {
        ++ipow;
        lower_bound = lower_bound / 10;
    } else {
        int i = pow(10, ipow) * input;
        if (i < upper_bound) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: That's just one testcase. Try 1561.

Comment: returns true, sad that i cant downvote you for downvoting without test

Comment: I think he means `lower_bound = 1561;`, other variables remaining the same.

Comment: Anyway, you're returning true any time `lower_bound <= input`, which clearly is not correct.  -1.  Try testcase `81 in (700, 799)`.

Comment: Yup, it's now equivalent to T_12's solution, although a bit slower with the `pow`.